# Tabela não é gerada em banco de dados Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Essa roda normal:

```
create table M_VENDEDORES (
ID_VENDEDOR number (10,0) not null,
NOME varchar2 (100) not null,
CPF number (11,0) not null,
ENDERECO varchar2 (100) not null,
NUMERO varchar2 (10) not null,
CEP number (11,0) not null,
constraint PK_VENDEDOR PRIMARY KEY (ID_VENDEDOR),
constraint UK_CPF unique (CPF)
);
```

Essa roda normal:

```
create table M_VENDAS (
ID_VENDEDOR number (10,0) not null,
MES varchar2 (100) not null,
VENDAS number (10) not null,
constraint FK_ID_VENDEDORES foreign key (ID_VENDEDOR)
references M_VENDEDORES (ID_VENDEDOR)
);
```

Essa roda normal:

```
create table M_FORNECEDORES (
ID_FORNECEDOR number (10,0) not null,
NOME varchar2 (100) not null,
CNPJ number (14) not null,
constraint PK_FORNECEDOR PRIMARY KEY (ID_FORNECEDOR)
);
```

Essa não roda normal:

```
create table M_ESTOQUE (
ID_FORNECEDOR number (10,0) not null,
ID_ITEM number (10,0) not null,
NOME varchar2 (100) not null,
MODELO varchar2 (100) not null,
TAMANHO varchar2 (10) not null,
MARCA varchar2 (100) not null,
ESTOQUE number (100) not null,
constraint PK_ITEM PRIMARY KEY (ID_ITEM),
constraint FK_ID_FORNECEDOR foreign key (ID_FORNECEDOR)
references M_FORNECEDORES (ID_FORNECEDOR)
);
```

Retorna esse erro:

```
Log do erro: create table M_ESTOQUE (
ESTOQUE number (100,0)
)
Relatório de erros -
ORA-01727: o especificador de precisão numérica está fora da faixa válida (1 a 38)
01727. 00000 -  "numeric precision specifier is out of range (1 to 38)"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está aqui:

```
ESTOQUE number (100) not null,
```

Um número com 100 dígitos está além do que o Oracle consegue processar. O limite dele é 38 dígitos.

Há duas posssíveis saídas:

- Diminuir o tamanho do campo.
- Mudar ele para `varchar2`.

Se esse campo só irá armazenar um código de alguma coisa (mesmo que esse código seja uma sequência de dígitos), recomendo usar `varchar2` (talvez seja os casos dos campos `CEP`, `CPF` e `CNPJ`).

Se esse campo representa a quantidade em estoque de um produto, com certeza trabalhar com 100 dígitos é um exagero e uma quantidade de dígitos bem menor (tal como 10) seria mais que suficiente.

Comment: Boa noite Victor!

Muito obrigado entendi oque eu estava fazendo errado.

Deu certo valew mesmo.